# Dynamically change html being served real-time by users for SPA (node.js)

Tags: node.js, express, dynamic, websocket, server-side

I'm building my first real-time application and don't understand how something works. I have an express.js web-app using websockets to push real-time changes by users to other users.

Say we have an auction and all users see the exact same product displayed with a bid price of $0. One user bids $200, the web-app websockets are working, and all other **connected** clients see the bid price go from $0 to $200.

The problem is, say a new client comes to onto the web-app. They still see the bid for the same product at $0 because my server is serving the same static html file, it isn't updating the html file when the websockets are being used to update all **connected** clients, in this case updating the bid price.

I feel there is a simple thing I'm missing, please let me know what it is, I've been utterly perplexed on this for the last few days (so much I created an account b/c I couldn't find the answer).

Basically, how do you change the html file that is being served to dynamically update with the latest user-generated data. Say a user generates some content, pushes to server and server now serves that version of the web-page (the latest up-to-date version) to anyone who connects/goes to my website url.

If you need any code or further explanation of my problem *please* ask, I'd be extremely grateful for any closure. Thanks for your time!

**EDIT:** I believe it has something to do with me using Express.js to serve 'static' files. This is the code I use to serve the files.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

The last line is Express serving the files statically. Is that what makes it impossible to update the index.html/what should I be using instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood the request, you want serve a page with user data inside.

You need to create a route for every page you need for "render" the page with data before serve it.

This express [example](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) can be very usefull for you. That explain how to use template engine with expressjs.

I put here the code for easy read.

```
app.set('view engine', 'pug')
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!' })
})
```

in index.pug

```
html
  head
    title= title
  body
    h1= message
```

the example use pugjs as template engine but you can use other or implement your one.

Comment: Thanks Sergio Donati , I believe this may be what I need. Since I have only one page (index.html) I don't need to create any extra routes I'm assuming.